# What Can I Connect To ExpressPort Slot?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hardware

I have a mid-2010 MacBook Pro.  It has an ExpressPort Slot connection that seems to have no uses without something else to connect in there.

What are the possible things that I could use this port for?

Answer (score 1):

SATA | Firewire | USB3 ports (usually for external HDDs;) Ethernet ports; Media Card readers; Thunderbolt ports; PCI bus extenders. [Sonnettech](http://www.sonnettech.com/Product/macbookaccessories/index.html) has quite a few options.